Actions of relative Weyl groups on Levis in $GL_n$
Recall that the Weyl group  $W= N_{G}(T)/T$ of an algebraic group $G$ acts on the maximal torus $T$ since $N_{G}(T)$ acts by conjugation by definition and $T$ acts trivially since $T$ is abelian. I am interested in replacing $T$ with another Levi subgroup $L \subseteq G$ and taking the relative Weyl group $W_{L} = N_{G}(L)/L$. In this case we cannot repeat the above argument since $L$ no longer acts trivially.
However, consider $G = GL_n$ now we can up to conjugacy pick Levis to be $L_{\lambda} = \prod_{i } GL_{\lambda_{i}}$ for some partition $\lambda$ of $n$. One can compute that $W_{L_{\lambda}}$ is a product of symmetric groups corresponding to repetitions in the partition $\lambda$.
For example, pick $L = GL_2 \times GL_2 \subseteq GL_4$  corresponding to the partition $(2,2)$. Then we have that $W_{L} \cong S_{2}$ the symmetric group. From this description it is clear that $S_{2}$ acts on $L$ by permuting the two blocks in $L$.
My question is how to see this action directly from the definition of $W_{L} = N_{G}(L) / L$ or to understand how the case of $GL_n$ is special.

I'm not convinced you get an action in the way you describe. As you say, $L$ doesn't act trivially and this is a problem. Different elements in a given coset will act differently even though they swap the same blocks in the Levi. At best you have an action on the set of Levi blocks or on the set of $L$ orbits
